# Long running tasks is cancelled - Celery5.2.6

Tags: python-3.x, django, celery

I have a project hosted in Digital Ocean in a Basic Droplet with 2 GB Ram. In my local machine, the long-running task runs between 8-10 minutes and is still successful.However in Digital Ocean droplets, often times the celery will not succeed in the long-running task.

Current celery - `celery 5.2.6`
I have two configurations in supervisor

1. Running the celery worker `celery -A myproject worker -l info`
2. Running the celery beat `celery -A myproject beat -l info`

This is the message from celeryd.log

> CPendingDeprecationWarning:
> In Celery 5.1 we introduced an optional breaking change which
> on connection, loss cancels all currently executed tasks with late acknowledgment enabled.
> These tasks cannot be acknowledged as the connection is gone, and the tasks are automatically redelivered back to the queue.
> You can enable this behavior using the worker_cancel_long_running_tasks_on_connection_loss setting.
> In Celery 5.1 it is set to False by default. The setting will be set to True by default in Celery 6.0.

```
warnings.warn(CANCEL_TASKS_BY_DEFAULT, CPendingDeprecationWarning)

[2022-07-07 04:25:36,998: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://localhost:6379//: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused..
Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)

[2022-07-07 04:25:39,066: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://localhost:6379//: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused..
Trying again in 4.00 seconds... (2/100)
```

For a temporary solution, what I did is to restart the server, and re-run new tasks, but this will not guarantee that the long-running task will be successful, the problem with this is the previously failed task will not restart.

My goal is,

1. Prevent long-running tasks from being canceled
2. If the long-running task is already canceled and cancellation can't be avoided, I need it to rerun and continue instead of starting a new task.

Is this possible? Any ideas on how?

Comment: seems like it cannot connect to redis server. How you installed redis server in digital ocean?

Comment: @Shishir Subedi only happens when a long task is running. For shorter running tasks, it works fine. Redis is installed by adding in the requirements.txt file and install some dependencies by using `apt-get`

Comment: as the warning suggested, turn `worker_cancel_long_running_tasks_on_connection_loss ` to True can redeliver the failed task to the queue, thus prevent it to be 'cancelled'

Comment: how to "turn" this feature on? where to do it in python or from celery command line?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the warning message, you can control this behavior with `worker_cancel_long_running_tasks_on_connection_loss` to prevent the task from being cancelled on connection loss. On your celery version it is off by default, so your tasks should not be cancelled. However, even if a late-acknowledging task completes successfully in this scenario, the task is still redelivered to the queue and will be run again -- this happens irrespective of this setting and is unavoidable for tasks with late acknowledgment.

This is why it is vital that you design your tasks to be [idempotent](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/glossary.html#term-idempotent).

If your job is not idempotent, an alternative solution is to have your tasks ack early (the default), but this risks the possibility that you may drop a task without it actually being completed.

If you *must* avoid dropping tasks, you must set `acks_late=True` to your task and it must be designed to be idempotent. This is necessary irrespective of the specific connection loss issue, as many other things can happen that interrupt your tasks and produce this same scenario.

> I need it to rerun and continue instead of starting a new task.

This comes down to how you design your task for idempotency. For example, you might want to have your job keep track of its progress in persistent storage, so when the task fails and is run again, it can determine how best to recover.